# Laravel 5: Performance with separate indexes in migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I'm trying to create a new migration for my new table with 4 indexes but encountered some issue

[image]

So what I did is, I separated my indexes

[image]

Question: Is there any difference in performance if I separated the indexes ?

Comment: Agregated index is totally different than (i.e.) 4 separated indices.

Answer (score 1):

It's the way to say to the Laravel Migration to add indices to that column, in order to get faster results when searching through that particular column. It's a common procedure in DB design when building tables. Just **"index"** some particular columns if you plan to make searchs in the table using those columns.

```php
$table->string('name')->index();
$table->string('email')->index();
```

Same as,

```php
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email');
$table->index('name'); // index
$table->index('email'); // index
```